# How to submit order form and get redirect to the user's page to see all others made by the user

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, heroku

I am developing an app where customers can make orders and get redirected to a page to see all the orders requested but I'm getting error here. Below is the error message. All I want is for a user who's registered to make order and get redirected to a page where all his orders will be displayed .
I will appreciate if someone could help me out here.

Here is the error message:

```
IntegrityError at /clients/add_item/
null value in column "location_id" of relation "clients_clientjob" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, , null, , , , 2021-07-14 12:10:05.555719+00, Pending, 2, null).
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://canwork.herokuapp.com/clients/add_item/
Django Version: 3.1
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
null value in column "location_id" of relation "clients_clientjob" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, , null, , , , 2021-07-14 12:10:05.555719+00, Pending, 2, null).
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py, line 84, in _execute
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.13
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 14 Jul 2021 12:10:05 +0000
```

This is the client(app name) model. This model is for client job that the user want to request

```
class ClientJob(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
            ('Pending', 'Pending'),
            #('On-going', 'On-going'),
            ('Completed', 'Completed'),
            )
    
    customer = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Customer', null=True,blank=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL,related_name='client')
   
      
    job_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique =False)
    text_description = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=True) 
    location = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Area' ,on_delete =models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique =False)
    phone =models.CharField(max_length=15,unique =False)
    email = models.EmailField(unique = False) 
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS,default='Pending')
    


    def __str__(self):       
        return self.job_name
      
   
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Client Job"
```

This is the client url:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *
from .import views

app_name = 'clients'


urlpatterns = [

path('add_item/', views.insert_ClientJob ,name='add_item'),

]
```

This is the  client view:

```
@login_required
def insert_ClientJob(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        form = ClientJobForms(request.POST)
        user_id=request.POST.get('id') 
        customer = ClientJob.objects.create(customer=request.user.details)
     
        if form.is_valid():
            product = form.save(commit=False)
            #customer = ClientJob.objects.create(customer=product.customer)
       
            #product.customer =customer
           
            product.save()
           
            messages.success(request ,"successful")
            return redirect('profession:user',user_id)
         
    else:
        form = ClientJobForms()
       
    return render(request ,'job_request.html' ,{'form': form})     


this is the client form:




class ClientJobForms(ModelForm): 
 
  class Meta:
    model = ClientJob
    fields = ['job_name','text_description','location','address','phone','email','status','customer']
    #fields ="__all__"

  

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ClientJobForms, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
    self.fields['location'].empty_label ='Your location' 



this is the client admin:


from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

# Register your models here.



class ClientJobAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('id','job_name','text_description','location','address','phone','email','date_created','status','customer')

admin.site.register(ClientJob ,ClientJobAdmin)






this is accounts model from where user model is derived from:
Account model is a different app from where i got user model

class Area(models.Model):
    area_code = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.location

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Area"



class Customer(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,blank=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL,related_name='details')
   address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
   phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
   date_created = models.DateTi`enter code here`meField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

   def __str__(self):
      return str(self.user)
```

Comment: It seems quite clear to me: you are not sending the location_id value

Answer (score 0):

`null value in column "location_id" of relation "clients_clientjob" violates not-null constraint`

This error tells me that you are getting this error because you are not providing the location attributes to your form. First, let me tell you ways you can fix this error.

1.) `location = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Area' ,on_delete =models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)`
Make the location field be nullable and blankable.

2.) Provide value for the location.

Now why this error is actually occurring. It might be because you are saving your form with commit being false, but then you are saving your form without the location field in it.

````
            #customer = ClientJob.objects.create(customer=product.customer)
       
            #product.customer =customer
           
            product.save()```
But I also don't understand why the form is being validated in the first place but I think this should fix your problem.

3.) You can provide location in the view itself.
````

Comment: how do i provide location in the view pls?@Dakshesh Jain

Comment: You are using ForeignKey therefore you have to give location using something like ```location_qs = location_model.objects.get(id=1) product.save(location=location_qs)```. Try this

Comment: customer
Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.             the above is the error is showing now.how can i solve it?